# Grails JSON from controller to GSP formatting html tag

Tags: json, grails

I am trying to send the following JSON from my controller to the GSP:

```
[
    "message":  errorList + '<br/>' + '<br/>' +
        'Rows loaded: ' + rows + '<br/>' +
        '<img src="${resource(dir: ''images'', file: ''twc-logo-002.png'')}" alt="logo" />' 
        + 'Errors: ' + errors + '<br/>' +
        'Yellow Issues: ' + yellowFlags + '<br/>' +
        'Red Issues: ' + redFlags
]
```

I am having a hard time with compiler errors on the line containing the image tag. I don't think I am escaping the inner quotes correctly. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using Groovy GStrings?
Something like `"message":  """$errorList <br/><br/>"""` looks much better than your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
    "message":  errorList + '<br/>' + '<br/>' +
        'Rows loaded: ' + rows + '<br/> \'<img src=\"${resource(dir: \'images\',file: \'twc-logo-002.png\')}\" alt=\"logo\" />' 
        + 'Errors: ' + errors + '<br/>' +
        'Yellow Issues: ' + yellowFlags + '<br/>' +
        'Red Issues: ' + redFlags
]
```

Comment: That seems to have worked I think. Except it can't find the image in my web-app/images directory where it is located.

Comment: It's better replace the ${resource.. with the physical address '/${grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName()}/images/twc-logo-002.png'

Comment: Agreed, always better to use the application context, I will try this. Thanks.